# Predict from Previously trained Model Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a Regression Model using tensorflow. The model saved file like

1. model.ckpt-4000.meta
2. model.ckpt-4000.index
3. model.ckpt-4000.data-00001-of-00002

Now if i want to use those file to predict output values from new data set (test data), how can i do that?

Comment: Did you try `model.load(model_name)` for loading your model and `model.predict(test_data)` for testing on new data?

Answer (score 1):

```
sess=tf.Session()

#First load meta graph and restore weights

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt-4000.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))

# create feed-dict to feed new data and specify the y variable to be evaluated
sess.run(y,feed_dict)
```

Comment: getting this error :Can't load save_path when it is None.

Comment: Check the path when restoring the model i.e. 
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path)

, and Check the parameters when saving the model i.e.
saver = tf.train.Saver(save_relative_paths=True)

Comment: I actually use this code, it automatically generate the files
dnn_model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor( hidden_units = [120, 100, 80, 60, 800], feature_columns = feat_cols, model_dir = 'model')